# Удаления ключа из массива сессии Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как удалить ключ из массива сессии?

```
 public function delete_product(Request $request){

    foreach (session('products') as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->id == $request->id) {
             unset(session('products')[$key]);

        }
        
   }

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отредактируйте массив и заново поместите в сессию:

```php
$products = session('products');

foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->id == $request->id) {
        unset($products[$key]);
    }
}

session(['products' => $products]);
```